# Java Repository can't implement method

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, micronaut, micronaut-data

I am using the Micronaut framework, and I have the following setup:
have an Entity called Transaction, with a Long ID, and three fields, a UUID, a String Report and a String State:

```
@Entity
public class Transaction {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;


private UUID uuid;

private String report;

private String state;
}
```

In a CrudRepository, I have defined the following query:

```
int updateByUuid(UUID uuid, String state);
```

This correctly updates my Transaction entity with the given new State.
Now I wanted to write a different query:

```
int updateByUuid(UUID uuid, String report):
```

Obviously this failes to build, since the signature is the same.
I tried to write the following:

```
int updateReportByUuid(UUID uuid, String report);
```

or:

```
int updateReportByUuid(String report, UUID uuid);
```

(So changing the parameters around)
This fails as well, with the error message of

```
Projections are not supported on batch updates
```

and

```
No possible implementations found
```

The only time it did not fail to build is when I changed the function to the following:

```
int updateReportByUuid(@Id Long id, String report);
```

But obviously this is incorrect (since I specified ByUuid, and as the first parameter I have given a Long id), and also not the functionality I want. What I want is for the database to find the Transaction I want to update by its' UUID, and update its' Report column.

Comment: Have you tried writing a custom query with `@Query`? That way the function name does not matter and you can name it something else.

Comment: I tried, and that's certainly an option. But if possible, I'd like to use this auto generation method, and I'm pretty convinced that the name updateReportByUuid is correct, and I can't figure out why it fails to build.

Comment: Another issue might be that while UUIDs are technically unique, this is not shown anywhere in the schema, thus the error for `batch updates`

Comment: I tried adding some constraint in the entity code, for example with @Column(unique = true), but it didn't help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why this is considered as a batch update is, because you are updating records on a non primary key field.

As mentioned above the field `uuid` is technically unique and you also declared it as unique but it is not a primary key. Therefore Micronaut Data considers it as a batch update.

You have at least the following two options.

- Convert the `id` field from `Long` to `UUID` and drop the field `uuid`. With that case your primary key is a UUID and your update methods will start to work.
- Tell Micronaut Data what to do by adding at `@Query` annotation.

Comment: Well that's sad. Well if there is no other way than I will be using @Query to implement this method. Thank you.